# Measure via circles?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, if we preset the measure $\mu D$ of a (open or closed or whatever on the boundary) disk $D$, and use them to approximate sets, instead of squares
$$m^*(X)=\inf_{\cup D_i\supset X}(\sum\mu D_i)$$
or
$$m^*(X)=\inf_{\cup D_i\supset X, D_i\mathrm{ disjoint}}(\sum\mu D_i)$$ and $$m_*(X)=\sup_{\cup D_i\subset X,D_i\mathrm{disjoint}}\sum\mu D_i$$
What will happen?

Can we even have $m^*(I^n)=1=m_*(I^n)$? Or if not, can we know the exact value?

The $m_*$ part looks right but I can not convince myself. (E.g. how to show that the sum will eventually reach 1?)

I don't even have any idea for the $m^*$ part, though this seems not right (We must have considerable overlaps, so calculating the exact value may be fun).

For the disjoint $m^*$ part, it seems we must have a big circle covering all the square. (otherwise we leave uncountable points on the boundary, all of them need to be tangent to a circle, while the total amount of circles should be countable to be summable.)

Comment: I didn't think in measure theory it was required that the union of "things" for the outer measure $m^*$ (boxes or discs as in your question) had to be pairwise disjoint. One just takes the inf of the sums of areas for all possible coverings, without regard to any overlaps. It makes sense for the inner measure to require no overlaps, since one is taking a sup in that case.